# Using <c:set> not working

Tags: jstl

I am using this code in order to make a conditional output.

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{selectOneMenuValue eq 'OK'}">
        <c:set var="myVar" value="OK"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <c:set var="myVar" value="NOT OK"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
<h:outputText value="${myVar}"/>
```

When the *selectOneMenuValue* receives another value from the user, I render the form in order to evaluate again the conditional statement and print the result to the user

The above code does not work well, it prints *"NOT OK"* when *selectOneMenuValue eq 'OK'*

However, the bellow code works well/prints the text correctly:

```
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="#{selectOneMenuValue eq 'OK'}">
        <h:outputText value="OK"/>
    </c:when>
    <c:otherwise>
        <h:outputText value="NOT OK"/>
    </c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```

I do not understand what is the difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that variable `myVar` is not visible outside the `c:choose` block.
I have changed accordingly the scope of the variable.